# Javascript accessing a variable in my html textbox

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

so I have a js file, lets call it foo.js and it has a variable count; this count is what I want to display in a textbox on the html end, which is a separate file.

How can I make the textbox, reference the variable which constantly is updated per minute?

Here is what I tried so far,

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var elem = document.getElementById("count");
        elem.value = countVal;
        </script>
```

Where I want to show it in HTML:

Shapes:

if I set elem.value to 5, or hello world, it works, but I want to set it to the constantly updating js value in a seperate page. I also tried creating a function in my js file, where I return the variable, and then calling that function in the html tag, but that did not work either.

I am new to JS, and I would appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Edit:
THIS IS NOT for a TIME INTERVAL, I have a variable, that based on some drawings, counts the shapes drawn, and I want to bring that to front end. That count.

MORE CODE:

my function in the .js file

```
function getShapeNumbers(){
    return shapeCount;
}



<script type="text/javascript">
            var elem = document.getElementById("shapeCount");
            elem.value = getShapeNumbers(); 
            </script>
```

where I want it displayed

```
Shapes:<input type="text" size="25" style="width:50px;" id ="shapeCount" />
```

it returns undefined in the textbox even if I change my function to return 50, it shows undefined. And if I just elem.value to 50, then that works. I want it set to my global variable

Comment: look into [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) it allows you to execute code at intervals you specify

Comment: @NathanP. its a variable that is updated automatically, it is NOT user specific. I just want to show that js variable on the front end, that's all.

Comment: @PatrickEvans that link didn't help.

Comment: @NathanP. yes, it's only two pages so far, just a js file which has all the work, and a html file for the rendering. I just want that variable that is being maintained by the js(many functions alter it), to be displayed in the count input field, so a user knows how many shapes are rendered so far.

Comment: @NathanP. that's fine, I know it resets, I just want to show it for the time being. I just want to make the progress of displaying that variable in the front end

Comment: @PatrickEvans It is MY VARIABLE, that I update myself, don't worry about the updating, I just want it to be in the front end. That one variable, count, that I calculate, in the front end. I am already able to get the value I want, in the variable, I just now want to display it.

Comment: @NathanP. It is declared outside the function, its a global variable. I just don't know how to make my textbox = to the javascript variable, define in its own .js file

Comment: @NathanP. I want a textbox that has the value of that variable, the count variable is of course a global variable.

Comment: @PatrickEvans And that does NOT work :(

Comment: Show us more code, or it'll be difficult

Comment: define does not work? are you getting errors? does the wrong value get used what? show the actual code that is creating and changing your variable, and how you are using it

Comment: @PatrickEvans I am getting error undefined please look at my new code above

Comment: @NathanP.please look at my code above

Comment: @PatrickEvans You can assume getShapeNumbers() returns the correct value, or a constant say 2500, I now then want the front end to display 2500 in that textbox....adn constantly update when the variable is updated too, or for now just display the darn thing

Comment: show where shapeCount is defined, if you are getting `undefined` then it means your function does not know what `shapeCount` is

Comment: Do you actually include your file?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your js file is not loaded by the browser yet when you run the code `elem.value = newvalue`.

Run this only after all document html content be loaded:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('shapeCount').value = shapeCount;
};
```

Also, consider updating directly `input` when updating variable.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bx4SU/